# Assigning a method (self.frames) to a empty dictionary, and not a variable?

Tags: tkinter, variable-assignment

Why is "self. frames" assign to a dictionary and not get flagged as an error? "self. frames" is a variable or a method? I'm sorry, I got confused while watching the tutorial on learning Tkinter.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="clienticon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC client")
        
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is "self. frames" assign to a dictionary and not get flagged as an error? "self. frames" is a variable or a method?

It's not flagged as an error because there is nothing wrong with it. It's a normal instance variable.